# Word-Problem on Forbidden Position Permutations (Derangement)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, word-problem, derangements

**Problem**
On the way into a party everyone checks a coat and a bag at the door.
On the way out , the attendant hands out coats and bags randomly.
In how many ways can this be done if "One may get one's own coat, or bag, but not both."?

**My Answer**
$$\boxed{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \left[ \binom{n}{k-1} D_{n-k+1}\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} (n-i)!(-1)^i\binom{k-1} 
 {i}\right)\right]}$$ where $\binom{n}{r}$ denotes Binomial Coefficient. $D_n$ denotes the number of ways to derange $n$ objects

Is my answer correct$?$ And also can it be simplified further$?$

Comment: [Here's a link to a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Learn how to use it; your questions will be better received here if you do.

Comment: The picture is sideways and there are crumbs on the picture.....

Comment: Some of the notation on the far right is very difficult to read.  This is what I can read so far.  Please let us know what is missing or incorrect with the typesetting of the equation:  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \left[ \binom{n}{k-1} D_{n-k+1}\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} (n-i)!(-1)^i\binom{k-1}{i}\right)\right]$   (*here I use the more common $\binom{n}{r}$ notation for the binomial coefficient.  I also assume that $D_n$ denotes the number of ways to derange $n$ objects*)

Comment: Your interpretation is right , JMoravitz. (I'm really sorry about my handwriting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many different ways to express the result.  I do not follow your logic to reach the answer appearing in the image, but here instead is my logic and solution.

Answer the related question of "*In how many ways can the coats and bags be returned such that* **at least one** *person gets* **both** *their coat and bag back*"

Let $A_i$ denote the event that person $i$ gets both their coat and their bag back.

We try to count $\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i\right|$.

By inclusion exclusion and symmetry: $\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i\right| = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{i}\left|\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^i A_k\right|= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{i}((n-i)!)^2$

Why is $\left|\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^i A_k\right|=((n-i)!)^2$?  If the first $i$ people all get their coat and bag back, then those are already known in the arrangement.  What is unknown is who among the remaining $n-i$ people received what coat and also who among the remaining $n-i$ people received what bag.  There are $(n-i)!$ ways to distribute the remaining coats and then another $(n-i)!$ ways to distribute the remaining bags remembering that we could care less if any of the remaining $n-i$ people happened to get their coat or bag or both or neither.  Applying multiplication principle gives the result.

Nobody getting both their coat and bag back is then the complementary event:
$$(n!)^2 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}\binom{n}{i}((n-i)!)^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: The sum in the last expression should range from $0$ to $n$ (a quick sanity check shows that the expression gives $-1$ for $n = 1$, $-1$ for $n = 2$, $-10$ for $n = 3$, etc. The mistake is in the first use of the inclusion-exclusion formula---that sum should range from $1$ to $n$, not $0$ to $n$.

Comment: @user38762 good catch that something was wrong... This post was from quite some time ago.  Looking at it, I believe you're right the limits are incorrect and should have stayed ranging from $1$ to $n$.  There is another error in the exponent of the $-1$, it should have been $(-1)^{i+1}$ instead.  I think that should cover the errors, but if you see something else feel free to ping further.